# Apply color after clicking radio input

Tags: html, css

I am editing an already created form where I extracted this code. I wished to replace the "radio buttons" with stars. I am having difficulty applying the color to the stars once clicked. I have done some testing but I am having difficulty on how to set the:

```
.uk-margin > label > div > input:checked, label {
    color: #ff0000;    
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.uk-margin {
    float: left;
    height: 46px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.uk-margin:not(:checked) > label > div > input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
}

.uk-margin:not(:checked) > label {
    float:right;
    width:1em;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#ccc;
}

.uk-margin:not(:checked) > label:before {
    content: '★ ';
}

.uk-margin > label > div > input:checked, label {
    color: #ff0000;    
}

.uk-margin:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.uk-margin:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
    color: #deb217;  
}
.uk-margin > input:checked + label:hover,
.uk-margin > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
.uk-margin > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.uk-margin > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
.uk-margin > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
    color: #c59b08;
}
```

```html
<div data-id="page#18" class="rate2 uk-margin">
   <fieldset data-yooessentials-form-field="tempi" style="border-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
      <div class="uk-form-controls">
         <div class="uk-margin uk-grid-small uk-child-width-auto uk-grid" uk-grid="">
            <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right uk-first-column">
               <div>
                 <input id="star1" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="1">
               </div>
               <div class="uk-margin-small-left">1</div>
            </label>
            <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
               <div>
                 <input id="star2" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="2">
               </div>
               <div class="uk-margin-small-left">2</div>
            </label>
            <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
               <div>
                 <input id="star3" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="3">
               </div>
               <div class="uk-margin-small-left">3</div>
            </label>
            <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
               <div>
                 <input id="star4" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="4">
               </div>
               <div class="uk-margin-small-left">4</div>
            </label>
            <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
               <div>
                 <input id="star5" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="5">
               </div>
               <div class="uk-margin-small-left">5</div>
            </label>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="uk-text-danger uk-text-small" data-yooessentials-form-field-errors=""></div>
   </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you describe a bit more what is to happen? If I click the star marked 5 should all the other stars become red automatically?

Comment: Look into CSS :has

Comment: @un Yes exactly, when you click on the star they should turn red

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet has removed the CSS which appears to have nothing to do with the problem in the question (e.g. those with .rate).

It starts again on the hover and checked states, using CSS :has to select when an input is checked or there is a hover.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.uk-margin {
  height: 46px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.uk-margin>label>div>input {
  position: absolute;
  rtop: -9999px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.uk-margin>label {
  width: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.uk-margin>label::before {
  content: '★ ';
}

.uk-margin>label:hover,
.uk-margin>label:hover~label {
  color: #deb217;
}

.uk-margin:hover>label::before {
  color: #deb217;
}

.uk-margin:hover>label:hover~label::before {
  color: #c59b08;
}

.uk-margin:has(:checked)>label::before {
  color: #ff0000;
}

.uk-margin:has(:checked)>label:has(:checked)~label::before {
  color: #c59b08;
}
```

```html
<div data-id="page#18" class="rate2 uk-margin">
  <fieldset data-yooessentials-form-field="tempi" style="border-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <div class="uk-form-controls">
      <div class="uk-margin uk-grid-small uk-child-width-auto uk-grid" uk-grid="">
        <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right uk-first-column">
               <div>
                 <input id="star1" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="1">
               </div>
               <div class="uk-margin-small-left">1</div>
            </label>
        <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
               <div>
                 <input id="star2" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="2">
               </div>
               <div class="uk-margin-small-left">2</div>
            </label>
        <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
               <div>
                 <input id="star3" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="3">
               </div>
               <div class="uk-margin-small-left">3</div>
            </label>
        <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
               <div>
                 <input id="star4" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="4">
               </div>
               <div class="uk-margin-small-left">4</div>
            </label>
        <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
               <div>
                 <input id="star5" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="5">
               </div>
               <div class="uk-margin-small-left">5</div>
            </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-text-danger uk-text-small" data-yooessentials-form-field-errors=""></div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Note: flex is used to show the stars in order (without a need to change the existing HTML) rather than float.

Comment: Excellent without javascript. The new property :has() solves many things.

Comment: Really perfect I like the nested :has as well one line of css instead of 2 loops in js

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I’d recommend updating the markup so the labels come after the inputs.

```
<input type="radio" name="star" id="star-5">
<label for="star-5">
  <span class="visually-hidden">5 stars</span>
</label>
```

This will allow you to use CSS selectors like `input:checked ~ label`. Here are some good resources:

- https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/custom-controls/#a-star-rating
- https://www.magentaa11y.com/checklist-web/star-rating/

---

**Update:** If you can’t change the markup you could try using the `:has()` selector ([caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/css-has)) to style labels that contain a checked input. Here’s an example https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2023/01/level-up-css-skills-has-selector/#linear-range-selection-based-on-state

Comment: I would have liked to use this code structure unfortunately it is given to me as I posted it and it is not possible to change it

Comment: @bastiag5 Oh, that’s too bad. In that case you could try the `:has()` selector to check for a checked input, e.g. `label:has(:checked)`. Here’s a good example https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2023/01/level-up-css-skills-has-selector/#linear-range-selection-based-on-state Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with css the way your HTML code is written, but you can easily with javascript. below the code, once you click on a star it adds the red color to the clicked star and the lower stars.

```js
const inputLabel = document.querySelectorAll('.uk-flex input')

inputLabel.forEach((label,index)=>{
  label.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    target = e.target
    for(let i=0; i<inputLabel.length;i++){
      inputLabel[i].parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove('color-it')
    }
    for(let i=0; i<=index;i++){
      inputLabel[i].parentElement.parentElement.classList.add('color-it')
    }
  })
})
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.uk-margin {
  float: left;
  height: 46px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.uk-margin:not(:checked) > label > div > input {
  position:absolute;
  top:-9999px;
}

.uk-margin:not(:checked) > label {
  float:right;
  width:1em;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size:30px;
  color:#ccc;
}

.uk-margin:not(:checked) > label:before {
  content:'★';
}

/* .uk-margin:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.uk-margin:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
  color: #deb217;  
} */


.uk-flex.uk-margin-right.color-it{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div data-id="page#18" class="rate2 uk-margin">
      <fieldset data-yooessentials-form-field="tempi" style="border-width: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
         <div class="uk-form-controls">
            <div class="uk-margin uk-grid-small uk-child-width-auto uk-grid" uk-grid="">
               <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right uk-first-column">
                  <div>
                    <input id="star1" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="1">
                  </div>
                  <div class="uk-margin-small-left">1</div>
               </label>
               <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
                  <div>
                    <input id="star2" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="2">
                  </div>
                  <div class="uk-margin-small-left">2</div>
               </label>
               <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
                  <div>
                    <input id="star3" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="3">
                  </div>
                  <div class="uk-margin-small-left">3</div>
               </label>
               <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
                  <div>
                    <input id="star4" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="4">
                  </div>
                  <div class="uk-margin-small-left">4</div>
               </label>
               <label class="uk-flex uk-margin-right">
                  <div>
                    <input id="star5" type="radio" name="tempi" class="uk-radio" value="5">
                  </div>
                  <div class="uk-margin-small-left">5</div>
               </label>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="uk-text-danger uk-text-small" data-yooessentials-form-field-errors=""></div>
      </fieldset>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am testing with your code but if I click on 3 I would like the first 3 stars to stay active in red like this example [link](https://www.magentaa11y.com/checklist-web/star-rating/)

Comment: I just edited the code as you suggested above.